# How do I sort rows by attribute "className" using Vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my current data:

```
<tr class="myInnerDivs">
<td class="fourth">John</td>
<td class="first">Andrew</td>
<td class="fourth">Aisha</td>
<td class="third">Jacquelyn</td>
<td class="second">John</td>
<td class="first">Simon</td>
</tr>
```

I tried the following:

```
//sort list rows by class name
$('.myInnerDivs').sort(function(a, b) {
  let className = $(this).attr('class');
  if (a.className < b.className) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}).appendTo('tbody');
```

So the rows should be sorted by class attribute in ascending order like below:

```
<tr class="myInnerDivs">
<td class="first">Simon</td>
<td class="first">Andrew</td>
<td class="second">John</td>
<td class="third">Jacquelyn</td>
<td class="fourth">John</td>
<td class="fourth">Aisha</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You’ll have to convert the words to numbers. You can’t say “fourth < second”, you’d need something like: “4 < 2”

Comment: @ParkingMaster thanks for the input, but I really need to use strings as class attribute values rather than numbers and then sort those strings(classes) alphabetically.

Comment: You can use a data attribute and use a number there so you can sort it based on that instead of the class.

Something like `data-sort-index=1` and when sorting make sure to cast it to a `Number` to be able to sort it the way you want.

Comment: What you would do is create a list (array), loop through all the elements you want to sort, push them to that list, convert their classes to numbers then sort them using Javascript. Then you would delete the original elements and loop through the list to put them back in order. (Also, I see you’re in the same area as me, so we should wrap this up because it’s midnight)

Comment: @ParkingMaster Thanks again, your detailed explanation sounds exactly like what I need, but I don't know how to write that programmatically. Can you please give an example of that in JavaScript? I'm still a JavaScript beginner.

Comment: Sure, do you need it now? I can definitely do it early tomorrow. I’m happy to help

Comment: @ParkingMaster Yes please I need it now if that's possible. Other than that I will have to wait until when I can get the correct answer.

Comment: "In vanilla Javascript" except the code is obviously using jQuery. Also note that your desired output is NOT in alphabetical order, "f" does not come after "t" in the alphabet. Can you edit your question to actually state what you want? You got an answer to your question as asked, and it doesn't suit your needs, which is a waste of the answerer's time (and yours!) and the reason we require questions to be well-formulated.

Comment: @JobGondwe Based on requirement, that "sort td element alphabetically based on the classname" is updated in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

So what you need to do is the following:

- Loop through the elements one-by-one
- Push them to an array
- You’ll need to somehow define numbers using their class name (I’m sure it’s possible)
- Using a simple sort function, sort them using that number
- Push all of the sorted elements to a new array
- Remove all the original elements
- Append the new array elements to where the old ones were

This sounds pretty long and hard but it’s pretty easy.

Here’s all of that in action:

```js
let wordNumbers = {
  "first": 0,
  "second": 1,
  "third": 2,
  "fourth": 3,
  "fifth": 4
};
// Add more if you have more elements

let elements = Object.values(document.querySelector(".myInnerDivs").children);

let oldElements = [];
let newElements = [];

elements.forEach(element => (oldElements.push(element.cloneNode()), element.remove()));

oldElements.forEach(element => {
  newElements[wordNumbers[element.className] - 1] = element;
});

newElements.forEach(element = > {
  document.querySelector(".myInnerDivs").appendChild(element);
});
```

I have not tested this so let me know if there are any problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer you have provided. But these classes are created dynamically by PHP, so we don't know what exactly the name of the class is going to be. What needed is to arrange those classes alphabetically no matter what the name of class might be in the dynamically created list of rows. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I don’t think that is possible. Only the human brain can do that

Comment: _"What needed is to arrange those classes alphabetically no matter what the name of class might be in the dynamically created list of rows. I hope this makes sense."_ - no it doesn't, at least not considering the initial example you have given. first first second third fourth fourth is _not_ in alphabetical order.

Comment: @ParkingMaster It is possible and I have answered it.

Comment: @Developer ok thank you for answering it. I don’t think I can figure that answer out lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this as:-

1. Use **toArray()** method to convert jquery object into array.
2. Use **localeCompare() with sort()** as we are comparing the string, to sort the array.
3. Finally use **append() inside forEach()** loop for placing the sorted items.

Here is the updated Code:-

```js
 let myInnerDivs = $('.myInnerDivs td').toArray();
    
 myInnerDivs.sort((a, b) => {
   let classNameA = $(a).attr('class');
   let classNameB = $(b).attr('class');
   return classNameA.localeCompare(classNameB);
 }).forEach((item)=>{
   $('.myInnerDivs').append($(item));
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="myInnerDivs">
<td class="fourth">John</td>
<td class="first">Andrew</td>
<td class="fourth">Aisha</td>
<td class="third">Jacquelyn</td>
<td class="second">John</td>
<td class="first">Simon</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Remember that, ** "it will not sort in a way that if class name is first then it will go to first" **, then second, then third and so on.

Instead **it will sort alphabetically** where td with class name first will come first, then fourth, then second, and then third and so on. Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have jquery in your code, so I'll skip that its use is acceptable:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
  $('.myInnerDivs').html( $('.myInnerDivs td').toArray().sort( (a, b) => a.getAttribute('class').localeCompare( b.getAttribute('class') ) ) );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="myInnerDivs">
    <td class="first">Simon</td>
    <td class="first">Andrew</td>
    <td class="second">John</td>
    <td class="third">Jacquelyn</td>
    <td class="fourth">John</td>
    <td class="fourth">Aisha</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>Arrange classes alphabetically</button>
```